# Direction vector from $\arctan(y/x),\arctan(z/x)$ and $\arctan(z/y)$

Tags: geometry

I have $3$ angles $\arctan(y/x),\arctan(z/x)$ and $\arctan(z/y)$ - please have a look for attached figure. Obviously those angles can be derived from a vector that defines the space diagonal of a cuboid.
These angles remain constant regardless of the length of the vector as long as its direction does not change.

My question is whether it is also possible to derive the direction of that vector from the $3$ angles.

I’ve searched the web and I also found a related question here: “Vector defined by $3$ angles” however the answer didn't helped me much. I would be glad if someone could give me a hint.

[image: vector]

Comment: Did you mean $\arctan$ instead of $\tan$ for angles? Also, specify which of [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22vector+defined+by+3+angles%22+site:math.stackexchange.com&client=ms-android-samsung-ga-rev1&prmd=ivsn&sxsrf=AJOqlzUymnSgmYjT7KeyjjSEWz0pAG_GCg:1673472634455&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiOyKuvu8D8AhW057sIHbtiBdAQrQIoBHoECBAQBQ&biw=412&bih=832&dpr=2.63) posts you are referring to. Pretend you're asking a question to a human in front of you.

Comment: Let $\;\alpha=\arctan(y/x)$, $\;\beta=\arctan(z/x)$, $\;\gamma=\arctan(z/y)$. The vector $\vec v$ can be obtained by the angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in the following way:

$$\vec{v}=\dfrac A{\sqrt{1+\tan^2\alpha+\tan^2\beta}}\,\hat i+\dfrac{A\tan\alpha}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2\alpha+\tan^2\beta}}\,\hat j+\dfrac {A\tan\beta}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2\alpha+\tan^2\beta}}\,\hat k$$ where $A$ is the length of the vector $\vec v$.

Comment: Thank you very much for commenting -

Comment: @First comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2095876/vector-defined-by-3-angles

Comment: @First comment: Thank you for correcting all typo's - of course it must be arctan instead of tan. I've added an updated fig too.

Comment: @Angelos comment: Thank you very much - this works great.